# OpenCV 3.0: Calibration not fitting as expected

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm getting results I don't expect when I use OpenCV 3.0 calibrateCamera. Here is my algorithm:

1. Load in 30 image points
2. Load in 30 corresponding world points (coplanar in this case)
3. Use points to calibrate the camera, just for un-distorting
4. Un-distort the image points, but don't use the intrinsics (coplanar world points, so intrinsics are dodgy)
5. Use the undistorted points to find a homography, transforming to world points (can do this because they are all coplanar)
6. Use the homography and perspective transform to map the undistorted points to the world space
7. Compare the original world points to the mapped points

The points I have are noisy and only a small section of the image. There are 30 coplanar points from a single view so I can't get camera intrinsics, but should be able to get distortion coefficients and a homography to create a fronto-parallel view.

As expected, the error varies depending on the calibration flags. However, it varies opposite to what I expected. If I allow all variables to adjust, I would expect error to come down. I am *not* saying I expect a better model; I actually expect over-fitting, but that should still reduce error. What I see though is that the fewer variables I use, the lower my error. The best result is with a straight homography.

I have two suspected causes, but they seem unlikely and I'd like to hear an unadulterated answer before I air them. I have pulled out the code to just do what I'm talking about. It's a bit long, but it includes loading the points.

The code doesn't appear to have bugs; I've used "better" points and it works perfectly. I want to emphasize that the solution here can't be to use better points or perform a better calibration; the whole point of the exercise is to see how the various calibration models respond to different qualities of calibration data.

Any ideas?

**Added**

To be clear, I *know* the results will be bad and I expect that. I also understand that I may learn bad distortion parameters which leads to worse results when testing points that have not been used to train the model. What I don't understand is how the distortion model has more error when using the training set as the test set. That is, if the cv::calibrateCamera is supposed to choose parameters to reduce error over the training set of points provided, yet it is producing more error than if it had just selected 0s for K!, K2, ... K6, P1, P2. Bad data or not, it should at least do better on the training set. Before I can say the data is not appropriate for this model, I have to be sure I'm doing the best I can with the data available, and I can't say that at this stage.

**Here an example image**

The points with the green pins are marked. This is obviously just a test image.
[image: Example image]

**Here is more example stuff**

In the following the image is cropped from the big one above. The centre has not changed. This is what happens when I undistort with just the points marked manually from the green pins and allowing K1 (only K1) to vary from 0:

Before
[image: Set A image, 1920 by 1080, distorted]

After
[image: Set A image, 1920 by 1080, undistorted]

I would put it down to a bug, but when I use a larger set of points that covers more of the screen, even from a single plane, it works reasonably well. This looks terrible. However, the error is not nearly as bad as you might think from looking at the picture.

```
// Load image points
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> im_points;
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1206, 1454));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1245, 1443));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1284, 1429));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1315, 1456));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1352, 1443));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1383, 1431));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1431, 1458));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1463, 1445));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1489, 1432));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1550, 1461));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1574, 1447));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1597, 1434));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1673, 1463));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1691, 1449));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1708, 1436));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1798, 1464));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1809, 1451));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1819, 1438));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1925, 1467));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1929, 1454));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(1935, 1440));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(2054, 1470));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(2052, 1456));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(2051, 1443));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(2182, 1474));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(2171, 1459));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(2164, 1446));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(2306, 1474));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(2292, 1462));
    im_points.push_back(cv::Point2f(2278, 1449));

    // Create corresponding world / object points
    std::vector<cv::Point3f> world_points;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        world_points.push_back(cv::Point3f(5 * (i / 3), 4 * (i % 3), 0.0f));
    }

    // Perform calibration
    // Flags are set out so they can be commented out and "freed" easily
    int calibration_flags = 0
        | cv::CALIB_FIX_K1
        | cv::CALIB_FIX_K2
        | cv::CALIB_FIX_K3
        | cv::CALIB_FIX_K4
        | cv::CALIB_FIX_K5
        | cv::CALIB_FIX_K6
        | cv::CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST
        | 0;

    // Initialise matrix
    cv::Mat intrinsic_matrix = cv::Mat(3, 3, CV_64F);
    intrinsic_matrix.ptr<float>(0)[0] = 1;
    intrinsic_matrix.ptr<float>(1)[1] = 1;
    cv::Mat distortion_coeffs = cv::Mat::zeros(5, 1, CV_64F);

    // Rotation and translation vectors
    std::vector<cv::Mat> undistort_rvecs;
    std::vector<cv::Mat> undistort_tvecs;

    // Wrap in an outer vector for calibration
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point2f>>im_points_v(1, im_points);
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point3f>>w_points_v(1, world_points);

    // Calibrate; only 1 plane, so intrinsics can't be trusted
    cv::Size image_size(4000, 3000);
    calibrateCamera(w_points_v, im_points_v,
        image_size, intrinsic_matrix, distortion_coeffs, 
        undistort_rvecs, undistort_tvecs, calibration_flags);

    // Undistort im_points
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> ud_points;
    cv::undistortPoints(im_points, ud_points, intrinsic_matrix, distortion_coeffs);

    // ud_points have been "unintrinsiced", but we don't know the intrinsics, so reverse that   
    double fx = intrinsic_matrix.at<double>(0, 0);
    double fy = intrinsic_matrix.at<double>(1, 1);
    double cx = intrinsic_matrix.at<double>(0, 2);
    double cy = intrinsic_matrix.at<double>(1, 2);

    for (std::vector<cv::Point2f>::iterator iter = ud_points.begin(); iter != ud_points.end(); iter++) {
        iter->x = iter->x * fx + cx;
        iter->y = iter->y * fy + cy;
    }

    // Find a homography mapping the undistorted points to the known world points, ground plane
    cv::Mat homography = cv::findHomography(ud_points, world_points);

    // Transform the undistorted image points to the world points (2d only, but z is constant)
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> estimated_world_points;    
    std::cout << "homography" << homography << std::endl;
    cv::perspectiveTransform(ud_points, estimated_world_points, homography);

    // Work out error
    double sum_sq_error = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        double err_x = estimated_world_points.at(i).x - world_points.at(i).x;
        double err_y = estimated_world_points.at(i).y - world_points.at(i).y;

        sum_sq_error += err_x*err_x + err_y*err_y;
    }
    std::cout << "Sum squared error is: " << sum_sq_error << std::endl;
```

Comment: "The points I have are noisy and only a small section of the image" Could you show that image? Why do you think that you get reliable distortion parameters if you just measure the distortion in a small section of the image?

Comment: I'll see if I can show the image. The points are all in the code above, so all the data is there to see how bad it is (from one test set, I ahve multiple, but this is a good representation). I don't think the parameters are going to be good from a small section with noisy samples, but I don't expect the full model with K1, K2 . . . K6, P1, P2 to get higher error than a straight homography (NO distortion parameters) when I'm using the training set to evaluate the error. That is, the distortion model is increasing error using the training set. This seems counter to expectations.

Comment: can you post undistorted result images? From my experience it might happen that undistortion is ok/good for pixel covered by your "calibration pattern" but might get very wild outside of it. Maybe that's some kind of overfitting (inside the calibration region) but not sure...

Comment: I can later, but that's not it Micka; what you describe is what I expected to happen. It IS wild outside, as expected, but it is actually a worse fit for the training points as well, which shouldn't be the case of overfitting was the problem.

Comment: in your sample image, the calibration point pattern nearly looks like a single line (from that perspective). Typically, those algorithms have problems with collinear points (because they dont give another dof). Do you get similar bad results for sceneries where point projections aren't "nearly collinear"? I'm looking forward to seeing more sample images and sample results :D

Comment: I know it is only one pair of images, but as you can see when cropped it is not quite as bad as it appeared before. The points might look like a straight line at that scale, but the original is 4k x 3k. There is quite a bit of space between those points (even compared to error). Having said that, it had occurred to me as well.

Comment: Can you post the calibration image too, the ones posted are the test images, right?

Comment: Also, how did you calculate the real world coordinates?

Comment: Mojo, I calibrated from these images. I didn't calculate the world coordinates, I measured them. I'm not sure how one would calculate world coordinates from an uncalibrated still image in order to calibrate. That seems a little bit like using unknowns to solve for themselves.

Comment: you can save the loop after
`// ud_points have been "unintrinsiced", but we don't know the intrinsics, so reverse that`

by doing:

`cv::undistortPoints(im_points, ud_points, intrinsic_matrix, distortion_coeffs, intrinsic_matrix); `

Comment: Did you calibrate on the large image and used the intrinsic matrix to undistort the cropped image? This will not work because the calibrated focal point (intrinsic_matrix(0,2), intrinsic_matrix(1,2)) will only be correct for the large image.

Comment: I may not have been clear, but I use a section cropped from the center. It should have a focal point identical to the large one. If we consider normalised coordinate, it may shift slightly simply because we have "magnified" every error by cropping.

Answer (score 1):

I would take random samples of the 30 input points and compute the homography in each case along with the errors under the estimated homographies, a RANSAC scheme, and verify consensus between error levels and homography parameters, this can be just a verification of the global optimisation process. I know that might seem unnecessary, but it is just a sanity check for how sensitive  the procedure is to the input (noise levels, location)

Also, it seems logical that fixing most of the variables gets you the least errors, as the degrees of freedom in the minimization process are less. I would try fixing different ones to establish another consensus. At least this would let you know which variables are the most sensitive to the noise levels of the input.

Hopefully, such a small section of the image would be close to the image centre as it will incur the least amount of lens distortion. Is using a different distortion model possible in your case? A more viable way is to adapt the number of distortion parameters given the position of the pattern with respect to the image centre.

Without knowing the constraints of the algorithm, I might have misunderstood the question, that's also an option too, in such case I can roll back.

I would like to have this as a comment rather, but I do not have enough points.

Comment: Thanks Trox. I'm not sure that I've understood you, or that you've understood me. I know which points go with which. They are identified in the scene and image, so RANSAC seems unnecessary. What do you mean different distortion model? I mean, the variables I'm fixing or not fixing are K1, K2 . .  + P1, P2. Fixing or not fixing them gives me a different distortion model. Or do you mean something totally different from the Brown model? Also, the points are sometimes near the center, but usually not. Often they will be centered in y or x, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV runs Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm inside calibrate camera.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm/

This algortihm works fine in problems with one minimum. In case of single image, points located close each other and many dimensional problem (n= number of coefficents) algorithm may be unstable (especially with wrong initial guess of camera matrix. Convergence of algorithm is well described here:

https://na.math.kit.edu/download/papers/levenberg.pdf/

As you wrote, error depends on calibration flags - number of flags changes dimension of a problem to be optimized.

Camera calibration also calculates pose of camera, which will be bad in models with wrong calibration matrix.

As a solution I suggest changing approach. You dont need to calculate camera matrix and pose in this step. Since you know, that points are located on a plane you can use 3d-2d plane projection equation to determine distribution type of points. By distribution I mean, that all points will be located equally on some kind of trapezoid.

Then you can use cv::undistort with different distCoeffs on your test image and calculate image point distribution and distribution error.

The last step will be to perform this steps as a target function for some optimization algorithm with distortion coefficents being optimized.

This is not the easiest solution, but i hope it will help you.

Comment: I have a theory that it may have actually been because the OpenCV code seems to constrain the number of steps taken by the LM. I wanted to rebuild OpenCV and try it with a greater number of steps to see how it would go, but never got the chance. I no longer have access to the data unfortunately. I was hoping to go to a model I could generalise to 3d / 3d. I ended up using a variation on 8 points with some refinement and error estimation afterwards. Which isn't much different from the over constrained OpenCV approach.

Comment: You can always use Lev-Mar form eigen https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/index.html